# Css3 list-style-image not working

Tags: html, list, css

Im stucked in a very stupid problem right now.
Im trying to change the bullets in the ul-tag to antother image instead.
I have done exakt the way many other does on the web but it dosent work for me and i am so anoyed!!
My image is check.png and the image i showing just fine when i use the img src tag.

i have tried with both:

```
list-style-image: url('check.png');
```

and

```
list-style-image: url(check.png);
```

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="theList3">
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

CSS3

```
ul.theList3{
list-style-image: url('check.png');
```

}

[image]

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: That *should* work. The file path must be wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/Lnw61duo/

Comment: Hmm, try this notation : `ul{ /* list-style-... */ }` - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x26L4a88/

Comment: the image is right in the root folder..still dosent work..can it be the image that is to big? it is 32 × 32

Comment: the size shouldn't matter try url('./check.png'), or url('../check.png') that's because your css file maybe is under a sub-folder like /css ?